# AngularJS JSON Processing (like with ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to process json data in following manner:

```
$scope.activities = response.data;
console.log($scope.activities.length);
var list = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.activities.length; i++) {
    console.log($scope.activities[i].name);
    list.push($scope.activities[i].name);
}
var input = document.getElementById("myinput");
new Awesomplete(input, {
    list: list
});
```

Or how it's possible too (another case, but same principle):

```
<li ng-repeat="navItem in navItems" ng-click="itemClicked(item, $index)" ng-class="{'nav_list_item-current' : navItem.selected} " class="nav_list_item pure-u-md-1-{{navItemsCount}} pure-u-1-1">
    <a class="nav_list_item_link" href="{{navItem.link}}">
        {{navItem.name}}
    </a>
</li>
```

Where navItems is a JSON object.

**How is this possible in angular, I mean it's working but not really *nice*?**

Comment: What is your problem? Do you have an error?

Comment: I think he wants to use Awesomeplete with angular (e.g. with ng-repeat). His binding isn't very clean in general, but I am not sure what I can do here for him except recommend UI bootstrap and their dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you could put your awesomecomplete code in a directive to have "clean angular", but that's not really a five minute thing. Here is your database call data assignment simplified:

```
YourDatabaseCall().then(function(activitiesDataFromDb){
    //the _.pluck method gets you an array of activity names
    $scope.activities = _.pluck(activitiesDataFromDb, 'name');

    var input = document.getElementById("myinput");
    new Awesomplete(input, {
        list: list
    }); 
});
```

See http://underscorejs.org/#pluck, to copy their description of the pluck helper:

> A convenient version of what is perhaps the most common use-case for
>   map: extracting a list of property values. And their eexample:

```
var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}];
_.pluck(stooges, 'name');
=> ["moe", "larry", "curly"]
```

Comment: It's kinda stupid to use a library instead of simple Array.map

Comment: I don't know about "stupid", but I do generally agree with you, though you will find that most developers don't.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var input = document.getElementById("myinput");

$scope.activities = response.data;

var activityNames = $scope.activities.map(function(item){
    return item.name;
});

new Awesomplete(input, {
    list: activityNames
});
```

or even shorter

```
var input = document.getElementById("myinput");

new Awesomplete(input, {
    list: response.data.map(function(item){
        return item.name;
    })
});
```